# Firebase OTP Verification .Net Core web App

Tags: c#, firebase, asp.net-core

I have an application which allows users to verify phone number and to do this i need to generate OTP which is sent as an SMS to user's phone number. And the OTP can be used to verify the phone number.

I wish to use firebase to for this verification process.
How can I use firebase to verify phone number by generating OTP for my web application in .net core.

I need the code syntax or functions in C#

Answer (score -1):

hello friend i have a project with asp.net core and angular , the otp verification with angular after that you can redirect the page to you control. if you are interested i'll upload the source code